# How to create a layout that can position its inner contents if overflow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to create a layout which contain dynamic number of textviews, how to create the container layout to make it so it is possible to do something like this picture?[image]

Comment: extends ViewGroup and override onLayout

Comment: what does google said to you?

Comment: ask uncle Google for: flow layout android

Comment: Yes the correct answer is Flow Layout

Answer (score 1):

Use `TokenAutoComplete` library to do this:

Following link may solve your problem: https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete

```
<com.tokenautocomplete.ContactsCompletionView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```